# Prove that if $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if the Matrix $M^B_A$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Let U and V be two finite dimensional K-vector spaces with the Basis A and B and let $f: U → V$ be a homomorphism.

Show the following:

$$f \text{ is Isomorphism} \Leftrightarrow M^B_A(f) \text{ is invertible.} $$

My thoughts thus far:

- If i can show that f is an automorphism then the invertibility of the matrix should be trivial, since then U = V and thus the inverse has to be part of the set as well (?)
- I know that if f is isomorphism then Phi(M) is an isomorphism, since $f = K_B^{-1} \circ \phi_A \circ K_A \implies \phi_A = K_B \circ f \circ K_A^{-1})$, am unsure as to how i can use this tho..

Overall I think while i understand the basics of this topic theres a lot im still missing, so if you could explain how to do this in detail taht would be great.

Comment: What does $f$ being an isomorphism mean? What does it mean that a matrix is invertible? Can you find a link between those definitions?

Comment: @YoungMath well, $f$ being an isomorphism means its a bijective linear function from U to V.

The matrix being invertible means its determinant is not 0, its kernel is trivial and the linear mapping of $x to Ax$ is bijective from $K^n$ to $K^n$

Im unsure on how i can connect thsese two tho